# Using es6 arrow functions inside class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When i change a function `draw(){ //}` to `draw = () => { // }`
I am getting an error like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =".
What may be the reason?

Comment: You will need to use babel's [Class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor you can have `this.draw = () => {//}` but there isn't really much point in doing this. `draw(){//}` should be fine for anything you want.

Below, in my example, I've shown both use cases as you can see nothing is saved by using an arrow function.

```js
class StandardFunction {
  draw() {
    console.log('StandardFunction: you called draw')
  }
}

class ArrowFunction {
  constructor() {
    this.draw = () => {
      console.log('ArrowFunction: you called draw')
    }
  }
}

const test1 = new StandardFunction();
const test2 = new ArrowFunction();

test1.draw();
test2.draw();
```

I hope you find this helpful

Answer (score 20):

First of all, you probably shouldn't do that. Why? Well, because arrow functions are not semantically the same as regular functions.

If you register the functions as `this.draw = () => {//}`, then every instance of your `class`* will have a duplicate definition of that function which is a waste of space and a misuse of some core language features such as prototype inheritance.

`draw()` on the other hand registers that function on the `prototype` so that definition of the draw function can be shared between all instances and even changed dynamically for ALL instances at the same time.

Comment: This is a good answer, normally it is good to include links and blockquotes for citation, it means more people will read it 

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use babel's [Class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), which will transpile:

```
class Picture {
  draw = () => {
    console.log('drawing')
  }
}
```

into:

```
class Picture {
  constructor() {
    this.draw = () => {
      console.log('drawing');
    };
  }
}
```

You can try it in this [repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAKCWwAuBXATgU2gbwFDWgBM0wB3aAXmgAoBKSgPh3wOjBAzSWoHJiz4AOwDmPWiwC-uKbllz5CxUuUqlQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2)  (make sure to enable the `class properties transform plugin`)